# Adding a restriction to MySQL COUNT() to only consider a maximum of 3 rows per day?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT (COUNT(id) * 5) AS total FROM content WHERE author = 'newbtophp'
```

I also have a column called `content_timestamp` (which contains the UNIX timestamp of when the content was created).

The MySQL query is functioning fine, however I only want the `COUNT(id)` to consider a maximum of `3` content per day (so if the table `content` contains more then `3` rows of data `WHERE` the day (+ month + year) of the `content_timestamp` is the same then only consider the first 3 and disregard the rest) - this is where I believe the `content_timestamp` will become useful.

However I'm unsure on how to do this?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will it work for you?

**Update**

```
SELECT 5*SUM(IF(num_content>3,3,num_content)) 
FROM
(
SELECT DATE(content_timestamp) as dt, COUNT(id) as num_content
FROM content     
WHERE author = 'newbtophp'
GROUP BY DATE(content_timestamp)
)a
```

Comment: Will the COUNT(id) only consider 3 rows of data per day?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, however seeing as the DATE() function only accepts the date in the MySQL format, I'm guessing I'd have to add FROM_UNIXTIME() ? and was the "a" at the end of the query a typo?

Comment: `a` is a table alias (without it you will get `each derived table must have an alias` error). Sure, you you need to convert timestamp with `from_unixtime` if you store it as a timestamp.